# Axios Intercept not applying token from localStorage on first call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

So I have a problem with my Vue application, where my axios intercept doesn't apply the authorization token.

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")
  console.log("Token is: ", token)
  console.log(typeof token)
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  console.log(config)
  return config
});
```

As you can see I've console logged my Token, before applying it to the Auth header, however this is what I get in my console log.

[On the first request the token prints just fine, but inside the header, it's set as null and I get a 422 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjN21.png)

[on the second API request, my token applies just fine, and I receive data back.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoyQK.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this stage, the `config` object passed to your interceptor has already been merged with the defaults so assigning the token to `axios.defaults.headers.Authorization` isn't going to affect the current request's config.

With that in mind, all you need from your interceptor is...

```
config => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")
  config.headers = Object.assign({
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }, config.headers)
  return config
}
```

I've used `Object.assign()` with the current headers last so as not to overwrite any existing `Authorization` header.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I was about to resort to setting the headers in the store on the login action, but I much prefer this way.